# REST API Performance issue in Magento 2

Tags: rest, magento2, magento2.4

Is anyone here heavily using Magento rest API for catalog data (products/categories/attributes/sets/groups) persistence? like not once in a while but more as a system integration. how is the performance in general? what throughput could you achieve and do you make use of async/bulk endpoints?

I am getting responses with a single POST/PUT in about 6s - 7s which I think is too much. As I have about 25000 products in my store

Do you have any suggestions on what can be done to improve the performance of REST APIS?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that this was because of the B2B feature of shared catalogs enabled I try to disable the shared catalog from the Admin Configurations and REST API performance just boost drastically.

As shared catalogs are like having lots of permissions for specific products for all the shared catalog groups created and that's why it's taking a lot to respond.

We customized the shared catalogs and bypass the permissions logic when the products have been created from REST APIS